# Unexpected type error while deleting an object

Tags: java, null, unexpectendoffile

I have an ArrayList of EnemyVehicle objects. Its name is *enemies*. When I try to delete an object of EnemyVehicle class, just like in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5757552/deleting-an-object-in-java), I get unexpected type error:

```
required: valuable
found: value
```

That's my code:

```
private void enemiesTurn()
{
    for(int i = 0; i<enemies.size(); i++)
    {
        if(enemies.get(i).isDestroyed())
        {
            enemies.add(getNewRandomVehicle(difficulty));
            p1.setScore(p1.getScore() + 20);
            enemies.get(i) = null;
        }
    }    
}
```

What can i do?

Comment: wouldn't you prefer to remove the object from the ArrayList? if that is the case you should consider the order of your iteration, as described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714233/remove-item-from-arraylist)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of `enemies.get(i) = null;` do `enemies.remove(enemies.get(i));`

EDIT: This is because `enemies.get(i)` is a value, not a variable and you cannot use it on the lefthand side of operations. The lefthand side of operations must include variable in some manner.

Comment: But i am trying to delete the object from memory, not from the arraylist

Comment: @EmreSülün You don't delete objects from memory. That's the garbage collector's job.

Comment: Although removing an element of `enemies` while iterating over it will result in a `ConcurrentModificationException`.

Comment: @EmreSülün Kayaman is correct. Unless you have a reference to the the object elsewhere, once you remove it from the arraylist the garbage collector will remove it from memory for you.

Comment: I have one more question. What is the reason of this error?

Answer (score 0):

When you're deleting stuff from an ArrayList or any List types. You should use an Iterator.

```
for (Iterator<ClassName> it = enemies.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
     ClassName objectName = it.next();
     if(objectName.isDestroyed()) {
            enemies.add(getNewRandomVehicle(difficulty));
            p1.setScore(p1.getScore() + 20);
            it.remove();
     }
}
```